# Javascript remove item from data by id

Tags: javascript

I have some data:

```
data = [
    {id: 1, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
    {id: 3, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
    {id: 6, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0}
];
```

I want to remove the item with id of 6.

So I have tried this:

```
function remove(id) {
    data.splice(data.indexOf(6), 0);
}
```

But it's not working.

How can I fix this function?

Comment: `data` is an array of objects, it doesn't contain `6` anywhere in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex)

```js
data = [
    {id: 1, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
    {id: 3, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
    {id: 6, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0}
];

function remove(id) {
    data.splice(data.findIndex(d => d.id === id), 1); 
    // here 2nd arg is 1 instead of 0 or it removes nothing
}
remove(6)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
data = [
    {id: 1, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
    {id: 3, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
    {id: 6, cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0}
];


function removeItem(arr, id){
    return arr.filter(item => item.id !== id);
}

data = removeItem(data, 6);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
function remove(id) {
  data =  data.filter(item => item.id !== id);
}
```

Filter function will return all items that do not have the ID thats provided as a param.